# OCR image recognition background noise reduction

Tags: ocr

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjIAg.png)

This is my image identification. I used PaddleOCR, and the current result is "un V deli."
But what I want is to identify it as "ACH."
Is there any way to remove the background, including those numbers, and only leave "ACH"?

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia5gF.png)

I have tried finding the edges of the subject and increasing the contrast, but the words in the background are also white, so it's difficult to distinguish.